# Two TextViews inside RelativeLayout with proper respond to rtl locale

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How can I create 2 `TextViews` in a `RelativeLayout` that look like this in `LTR` and `RTL` locales.

(Table is just for clearing what I mean, it's not part of my question)

**LTR**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║  txtView1  ║                        txtView2                           ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**RTL**

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════╗
║                           txtView2                          ║ txtView1 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════╝
```

currently I'm using margins but this doesn't seem right:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        android:textColor="?attr/info_color"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtView1"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't use `setLayoutDirection`, `minSdkVersion` is below 17"

Comment: I think you just need to set their width to "wrap_content"

Comment: @W0rmH0le If I do this textviews will not change directions on `RTL` locales

Comment: @DastakWall Just to clarify, you need textView2 to take ~80% of the width and textView1 to take ~20% of the width?

Comment: @ChrisvinJem Yes, also respecting directions on locale change

Comment: @DastakWall You could try replacing `RelativeLayout` with `LinearLayout` and use `layout_weight`.

Comment: @ChrisvinJem tried, it didn't respect layout direction. I don't know maybe I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can:

1 - Set `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content` in `TextView1`.

2 - Align `TextView1` to parent's start

3 - Align the `TextView2` at the end of `TextView1`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtView1"
        android:text="TextView 2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result:

**LTR**

[image]

**RTL**

[image]

**EDIT**

As well mentioned in the comments, you can use a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtView1"
        android:text="TextView 2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work properly for me.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layoutDirection="locale"
        android:textDirection="locale" //Works as expected when I set rtl or ltr
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:text="Something"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textDirection="inherit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="or the other"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:textDirection="inherit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "minSdkVersion is below 17"

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't notice that. (Also, I thought Android only supported RTL from API 17?)

Comment: Well, in that case I guess you could try making separate layouts (layout-ldrtl,layout-ldltr), although, I'm not certain if they will work properly below API 17.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then I guess your last resort would be to programmatically determine the locale and set the layout params.